# ¿Cómo puedo redireccionar una ruta con react-router-dom al realizar un evento submit?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Tengo un formulario y quisiera que al hacer submit se redireccione a una ruta en específica. Estoy usando react-router-dom y debe haber alguna forma de redirigir. Quisiera la forma más simple para hacerlo. No quiero que valide al usuario, solo es el front para una aplicación, por ello solo quiero un enrutado fácil y rápido. Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Login = ({ actualizarUsuarioLogeado }) => {

  const [error, guardarError] = useState(false);

  const iniciarSesion = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    actualizarUsuarioLogeado(true);
    guardarError(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={iniciarSesion}
        >
          <h3>Login</h3>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
              <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>


          <input
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
            placeholder="Submit"
          ></input>


          <p className="forgot-password text-right">
            Forgot <a href="#">password?</a>
          </p>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando React-router, puedes utilizar el objeto `history`, el cual tienes tres maneras de brindar a tu componente.

### withRouter

La primera manera es utilizando la función `withRouter`, la cual tienes que importar:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Esta función la utilizas en tu `export` encapsulando a tu componente:

```
export default withRouter(Login);
```

Y con ello obtienes acceso al objeto `history` que puedes utilizar para hacer la redirección:

```
const Login = ({ actualizarUsuarioLogeado, history }) => {
  ...
  const iniciarSesion = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    actualizarUsuarioLogeado(true);
    guardarError(false);
    history.push('/home'); // <-- Objeto history
  }
  ...
}
```

### Hook useHistory

El enfoque más simple, consiste en usar el nuevo [*hook* `useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks):

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = ({ actualizarUsuarioLogeado }) => {
  const history = useHistory(); // <-- useHistory
  const [error, guardarError] = useState(false);
  
  const iniciarSesion = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    actualizarUsuarioLogeado(true);
    guardarError(false);
    history.push('/home'); // <-- Objeto history
  }
  ...
}
```

### Heredando el objeto

La otra manera (y que no recomiendo) es directamente heredando el objeto `history` desde el componente padre:

```
<Route path={`${props.match.url}/login`} exact render={(props) => <Login history={props.history}/> } />
```

y finalmente, el componente debe quedar igual que en el caso de `withRouter`.